# Can't download updates because "This update is not available for this Apple ID"

Tags: software-update

I keep getting this message when I type in my password to do an update.

> This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

The computer was bought by me and has only been used by me.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: is this in the Mac App Store? And is it an operating system update or an app update? What version of OSX/MacOS?

Comment: it's a 10.11.6 and it's an app update, iPhoto, iMovie and garageband and there's a security update.

Answer (score 3):

Try going to the "purchases" section in the App Store. Accept the free apps like iMovie and Garageband there.

Answer (score 3):

If you logged in to a new Mac with an existing Apple ID **go to the App Store** as [Non Plus Ultra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269300/281619) already answered. You should accept the free apps that came with the new Mac and link the license to your Apple ID.

In the new App Store you should **go to your account**, which can be found at the bottom of the menu on the left in the App Store. You will see all your previous purchases and a notification box including an **Accept** button. Click the button to add the license to your Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

After going around the houses with Apple Support, what fixed this for me was removing a duplicate version of the App in the Applications folder. There was a legacy version of GarageBand 6.0.5 in a folder as well as the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t update because it says “ bought with another Apple ID or refunded” delete those apps and then download them again using your Apple ID. This worked for me.